# How do I initialize a variable as null in R5RS?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, r5rs

While working on a project in Dr. Scheme, I initialized a variable as null as follows:

```
(define var null)
```

How can I do this in R5RS?

Comment: What do you mean by "initialize a string to NULL"?  null isn't a string.  A string is a sequence of characters.  The empty string is "", if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: sorry, editing the question.

Comment: [[R5RS null?\] - "Returns #t if obj is the empty list, otherwise returns #f."](http://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/r5rs-std/r5rs-Z-H-9.html?q=null%3F#%25_idx_428) - read API documentation. ([Useful search](http://docs.racket-lang.org/search/index.html?q=null%3F), coming from Racket).

Comment: To do that in R5RS, you do `(define var null)`. What's the problem?

Comment: @AlexisKing: R5RS doesn't recognize null as a literal.

Comment: @user2864740: yeah i knew about that, but i don't want to check if the obj is null, i want to explicitly assign it.

Comment: So what *is* a "null?" value? The documentation *said* what it is - "an empty list". So what *is* an empty list in Scheme?

Comment: @ofey Oh, huh. Whatever. Just do `(define var '())`.

Comment: I know that I can initialize the var to an empty string. I was hoping to initialize it to null because an empty string could have been a valid input in my program so I needed to differentiate between "" and null. So I didn't want to resort to initializing the var to an empty string. Hence the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Scheme, the conventional placeholder for "invalid" is `#f`, the false object. You can test for it using `not`.

(There is a `null?` procedure in Scheme that checks whether the object is the empty list, `()`. However, that should only be used for list contexts, and not as an "invalid" placeholder. Note that `not` only returns true for `#f`, and `null?` only returns true for `()`; be careful not to mix the two up.)

Comment: This is true, but if you're going to be consing onto it, you want its initial value to be `'()`, not `#f`.Especially if null is a valid value for your variable.

Comment: Anything you can cons onto to build a list, by definition, is not a sentinel.